# why is a gdb query WHERE clause invalid according to the ArcGIS REST API?

Tags: arcgis-server, sql-server, rest

**Update:** This only occurs when the layer being queried has a **join**.
It doesn't matter if it has a join to a different database or not. And the query that fails is not trying to access columns in the joined table.

In order to more accurately express the problem, I've used fully-qualified (4-part) column names below where required. See the updated WHERE clause below.

Original question:

We are using ArcGIS Server 9.3.1, Java, and ArcSDE with SQL Server 2005 sp2.

It would be very useful for us to be able to monitor our data periodically for defects, with a query such as

```
select * from sdeDLM.SDE.Lang_Polygons
where ISO_LANGUAGE_CODE_ID <> LEFT(ID , 3)
```

In ArcMap, I can do that query using Select by Attributes. I enter the above where clause and click 'Verify', and the expression is verified successfully.

But in order to monitor the data we need to use the REST API. We can successfully do REST queries with a where clause such as

```
WHERE sdeDLM.SDE.Lang_Polygons.ISO_LANGUAGE_CODE_ID IS NULL
```

or just

```
WHERE ISO_LANGUAGE_CODE_ID IS NULL
```

Those work just fine. FWIW, the URL for that REST query is:

```
http://ourServer:8399/arcgis/rest/services/DLM21_query/MapServer/2/query?text=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&where=ISO_LANGUAGE_CODE_ID+is+NULL&returnGeometry=false&outSR=&outFields=&f=html
```

But when I try a REST query with a where clause like

```
    WHERE sdeDLM.SDE.Lang_Polygons.ISO_LANGUAGE_CODE_ID <> LEFT(sdeDLM.SDE.Lang_Polygons.ID , 3)
```

the REST API returns the message:

```
Unable to perform query. Please check your parameters
```

As best I can tell, it's the LEFT() function that makes the difference. I have been able to successfully use where clauses with everything else in them, including '<>'.

The [REST API docs for querying a layer](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/rest/query.html) say that "Any legal SQL where clause operating on the fields in the layer is allowed."

The URL for the query that gives an error is:

```
http://ourServer:8399/arcgis/rest/services/DLM21_query/MapServer/2/query?text=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&where=sdeDLM.sde.Lang_Polygons.ISO_Language_Code_ID+%3C%3E+Left%28sdeDLM.sde.Lang_Polygons.ID%2C+3%29&returnGeometry=true&outSR=&outFields=&f=html
```

Is there a way to get the REST API to accept a where clause using Left()? Or a way to find out why it's not working?

I tried browsing the latest logs in C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\server\user\log. The file Server-20100929-143218.dat shows the following output from the time when the query failed:

```
String request received. Request size is 2629 characters.
QueryFeatureData2 has started.
Preparation for method: QueryFeatureData2 has started.
Preparation for method: QueryFeatureData2 has completed.
Query Operation for method: QueryFeatureData2 on layer &apos;Language Polygons&apos; has started.
**GeoDatabase Error :An invalid SQL statement was used.**
QueryFeatureData2 has completed.
Method failed.HRESULT = 0x80040207 : This is a FACILITY_ITF error that is specific to the interface that returned this error. See the documentation of the interface that returned this error for information about this HRESULT.
ERROR INFO = An invalid SQL statement was used.
```

But why is the SQL statement invalid? Clearly the WHERE clause has been tested as valid elsewhere. And why would some of my WHERE clauses be accepted as valid, but not the one with LEFT() in it?

Comment: What is the data type of the 'ID' field?

Comment: Try the following, instead of the current LEFT method you're using, to see if it helps: LEFT(CAST(ID AS VARCHAR) , 3)

Comment: @mwalker: in ArcMap the data type in Text (length: 10). In SQL Server it's nvarchar(10).

Comment: @Michael Todd: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that; no change in behavior.

Comment: Can the 'ID' field be null?  If so you may need to wrap the column with a COALESCE or similar function.

Comment: @mwalker: there are no records where ID is null.

Comment: This is pretty bizarre. As a temporary workaround (just so you can continue getting things done), create a column on your table that consists of the 3 left-most characters of ID, then use **ISO_LANGUAGE_CODE_ID <> NEWID**. Hopefully someone here can come up with an actual solution, but that'll help in the mean time.

Comment: @Michael: Hmm. The thing is that we have replication which can update the ID field; then we have a calculation that is supposed to update the ISO_LANGUAGE_CODE_ID field from LEFT(ID, 3), but if that step gets forgotten after the sync, the monitor process should catch the mismatch. If we remember to update NEWID after the sync, we might as well update ISO_LANGUAGE_CODE_ID at the same time, so it kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Michael I would create a SQL Server view that calculates LEFT(ID, 3), but the view has to take into account the delta tables... and I don't know of a way to do that.

Comment: You can create a [multi-versioned view](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Using%20multiversioned%20views) if you need to access the data outside the context of ESRI products. The only problem _I_ have with that is that it seems to add several seconds to a query that should take microseconds (so it's a bit slow, but it still works). Again, this would just be a workaround until someone can figure out why you're having this issue.

Comment: @Michael: Awesome!! I have needed something like multi-versioned views for a long time but did not know that they existed. Besides the current task, they will be useful for a lot of things I've wanted to do. Please put the above in an answer so I can upvote it!

Comment: Did you check SQL server log that the query was reaching it ? Or is it stopped somewhere at a higher level ?

Comment: @Michael: FYI, I created such an MVV, and am able to use it for the monitoring I wanted to do. It's very fast... no performance probs. Thanks again mucho!

Comment: Very glad to hear that.

Comment: @GuillameC: where do I check that? Are you referring to a SQL trace, or is there some other log?

Answer (score 2):

I know in ArcGIS Desktop, ArcSDE field names must be enclosed in double quotes.  Maybe this [SQL reference](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=SQL%20reference) will help.

Comment: Thanks for this reference. Strangely, when I click on the Help for "Select by Attributes" in ArcMap, it says that with ArcSDE dbs there should be no quotes or brackets. But the ref you gave said there should be double quotes. However, I tried the REST query with double quotes, and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary workaround (since you're accessing the data via non-ESRI products), you can use a [multi-versioned view](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Using%20multiversioned%20views) to access the data.

A multi-versioned view will help because it takes into account the deletes and adds that represent each version; that way you don't have to worry about missing data when reading directly from the layer table via SQL.